# Browser text zoom (CTRL+, CTRL-) breaking Bootstrap 3 layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am building an online order entry page, and our CTO has his browser set to zoom roughly 150% by default.  This is breaking my layouts, and I was hoping someone would have an idea how to make the page work with around this.

[image: Zoomed text screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the measures in or rem. To fit the zoom and your reponsive design. Pixels are not good for zoomin

Example: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/full/XmRaGd/

```
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Documentacion: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Comment: I changed everything to use rems (I'm using Bootstrap Sass) and set the base font-size to .8rem.  All the other values are calculated based on that base value.  This improved things slightly, but it's still hosed at 150%.